# Preparation of tertiary Grignard reagents

Tags: experimental-chemistry, grignard-reagent

Has anyone a good and detailed experimental procedure to prepare tertiary Grignard reagents from tertiary alkyl halides on the lab scale (1-5 mmol)? The actual procedures in the literature are very scarce and limited to patents (large amounts). Older procedures exist only for tBuMgCl and not after 1932.

Comment: Hi, can you give some more detail about what you are trying to do?

Comment: "hindered" gringards are hard to make. Most require extreme conditions (well extreme by the standards of making gringards from primary alkyl halides). The least you will need to do is to reflux the solution in THF. But many will require extra steps to activate the Mg (like adding ground glass to Mg powder. Or even starting with something like Mg-anthracene. A few experiments like that are well worth attempting, but literature techniques often leave subtle bits out.

Comment: The likely problem with tertiary Grignard reagents is that they may, owing to their basicity, be prone to effect elimination of the HX from halide in solution to form an alkane and alkene. For this reason, vinyl magnesium bromide cannot be prepared in ether but it may be prepared in the better coordinating solvent tetrahydrofuran (THF).  t-BuMgCl is sold in THF. To activate magnesium, try the classic crystal of iodine or 1,2-dibromoethane.

Comment: A few mls of Dibal-H soln are also good for activating magenesium.

Answer (score 1):

Sterically hindered GRs are hard to make as @matt_black mentioned and although its synthesis looks single step and straight forward, most literature leaves bits out. I did find a recent publication where they mentioned the steps:

> ***tert*-butylmagnesium chloride**
>
> $$\ce{t-BuCl + Mg ->[I2,anhyd. Et2O]  t-BuMgCl}$$
>
> In a 3L, three-necked, round-bottom flask, fitted with a mechanical stirrer and a Hg seal, a 500-mL separatory funnel, and an efficient reflux condenser, were placed Mg turnings or powder (144g, 6.0 mol). The Mg was then covered with anhyd. $\ce{Et2O}$ (400 mL). Pure $\ce{t-BuCl}$ (~5 mL, with a crystal of $\ce{I2}$) was added to start the reaction. Stirring was begun and a solution of pure $\ce{t-BuCl}$ (555g, 6.0 mol) in anhyd. $\ce{Et2O}$ (1.5 L) was dropped slowly onto the Mg during 6-8 h. The reaction was practically complete when all of the halide had been added, but stirring was continued for further 15 min.
>
> <sub>Science of Synthesis: Houben-Weyl Methods of Molecular Transformations Vol. 7: Compounds of Groups 13 and 2 (Al, Ga, In, Tl, Be...Ba), Georg Thieme Verlag, **2014**</sub>

Alternatively, you can look at the [orgsyn article](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV1P0524) or this [2001 WOL article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/047084289X.rb399) but the steps/reagents are more or less same.

Comment: All these procedures shares with the patents I found on the subject, the large scale (usually from 500 mmol to 1 mol). On the smallest scale (2-8 mmol), I had no success. Magnesium is very active (washed with diluted HCl, H2O, EtOH, Et2O and dried) and it starts normal Grignard in seconds. Here I tried to further activate it with I2 or dibromoethane, but again no success. An old JACS ("The Yields of Some Aliphatic Tertiary Grignard Reagents and the Limits of their Usefulness as Synthetic Reagents", JACS 1933, 1559) discusses these problems, but again reactions are made on 1 mol scale...

Comment: @saiwa What exactly are you trying to convert? Is it just a haloalkane like tert-butyl chloride, or are there other functional groups? Nitro groups in particular can kill the Grignard reaction by oxidizing both the intended product and the magnesium metal.